# Best way to switch development databases in PHP?

Tags: php, database

Currently I'm working on a lot of updates for a database driven website.

So there's a file in the webroot called db.php which is included in every page. It has the connection details to the SQL database. This defaults to the live database.

We also have a file called db.local.php. Now, if this file exists, the connection details in that override the default values. Hence this file is not kept under source control, as it's unique to each set up.

We check if the file exists by going:

```
if(file_exists(getcwd().'/db.local.php')) {
    require_once('db.local.php'); 
} else {
//default database details
}
```

The problem is we use this file from multiple folders, not just the webroot (eg cwd of a script called from webroot/admin will be webroot/admin rather than just webroot). So if db.php is called from a script in another folder, the current working directory won't be the webroot so we won't see db.local.php. This is bad as then we are using the incorrect database.

Is there a way round this? (like a way to check the directory of the file which was pulled from, not where the script is executing from). Or is there a better approach to this problem than what has been implemented?

Comment: Do you foresee the need to move files around in the directory structure?  Is there a reason you can't just do an `include '../db.local.php';`?

Comment: That would work, but then if db.local.php isn't there, we have an issue. I see what you mean.

Comment: That would work, I guess, but then I need to do this in every file which includes it from any directory, which with that conditional test (if it exists) could be a lot of work.

So I now have a file called db.php.sample, with the structure of the file but no actual passwords, dbs etc. This is kept under git. db.php is not, and there's an ignore in .gitignore. So that way I can push changes and the db files aren't affected. I've found this to be the easiest way of doing it. Thank you everyone for your suggestions; they were all very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I do this:

```
switch (gethostname()) {
  case 'dev-local':
    define('SITE_URL', ....);
    define('TRIM_REQUEST_URI', '');

    require CONFIG . '/VM/database.php';
    break;

    ......
}
```

Each server has a different hostname.

Answer (score 1):

You can include db.local.php if you know the relative path to it from the script.  This will work regardless of the current working directory at the time you run the script.  For example, let's say you have

```
/foo/bar/www/db.php
/foo/bar/www/db.local.php
/foo/bar/www/index.php

/foo/bar/scripts/cleanup.php
```

Inside of cleanup.php, you can check for and include db.local.php like so:

```
$APPROOT = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..';
$DBLOCAL = $APPROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'www' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'db.local.php';
if(file_exists($DBLOCAL)) {
  require_once($DBLOCAL);
}
```

If you have a lot of scripts that do this, you might want to create an initialization file that sets those variables and include it in every script (using the same `__DIR__` method.)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an absolute path to look for the file using the 
`set_include_path` function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

```
<?php
ini_set('include_path', '/usr/lib/pear');
/*
// On Windows: 
ini_set('include_path', 'c:\sites\config');
*/
?>
```

**Edit:**
You could then just use
`require 'db.php';`
and PHP parser would know to look in that directory you specified w/ ini_set command.

You could also add the path to your `php.ini` file...

Comment: Setting an absolute path in every single file is a very bad idea.

Comment: And what happens if you're working on multiple sites on the same server?

Comment: Great question Sam. I would then resort to a bootstrap file of some sort to handle loading of necessary files...much like many MVC frameworks handle all(or most) loading mechanisms in a central location, so Gary G's solution looks like a better solution, for this question (After re-reading the OP's Question.)